# find data modifications entries in oplog in PSA setup

Tags: mongodb

I have a PSA replica cluster, and after doing an insert I can see entries in collections but unable to find entries in oplog with this command when insertions are done in a transaction and transaction.

```
db.oplog.rs.find().sort(
{$natural:-1}
)
```

Not sure what is the behaviour for insertions done in a transaction?

Comment: Add an mcve please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oplog entries for transactions are logged with

```
"op" : "c",     "ns" : "admin.$cmd"
```

and individual data modifications are logged inside as

```
"o" : {
    "applyOps" : [

        {
            "op" : "i",
            "ns" : "wordwatch.interactions",
            "ui" : UUID("cc279643-2fa9-42e3-8f5c-ca64b84f8c6b") ....
        }
 ]
}
```